# Creating Video from array of images and saving it to camera roll

Tags: ios, video, save, avassetwriter, avasset

I was trying to make a video from a set of images and I found some code and got it to work

but the video won't be saved to the photo library it gives me this error :

Documentsa.mov cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2 "This movie could not be played." UserInfo=0x922cf60 {NSLocalizedDescription=This movie could not be played.}

Here's the code I use :

```
 NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    UIImage * i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1650.JPG"];
    CGAffineTransform  transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI/180)*90);
    GPUImageTransformFilter * filter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc]init];
    [filter setAffineTransform:transform];
   UIImage * im = [filter imageByFilteringImage:i];
    im = [filter imageByFilteringImage:im];

    [self writeImagesToMovieAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,@"a.mov"] withSize:CGSizeMake(i.size.width, i.size.height)];

    NSString* exportVideoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",documentsDirectoryPath,@"a.mov"];

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (exportVideoPath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
```

And this is the code I use to create the video :

```
-(void) writeImagesToMovieAtPath:(NSString *) path withSize:(CGSize) size
{
    NSLog(@"Write Started");

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                             assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                             outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];


    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //convert uiimage to CGImage.

    int frameCount = 1;
    int kRecordingFPS = 30;
    UIImage * im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1650.JPG"];

    CGAffineTransform  transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI/180)*90);
    GPUImageTransformFilter * filter = [[GPUImageTransformFilter alloc]init];
    [filter setAffineTransform:transform];
    UIImage * i = [filter imageByFilteringImage:im];
    i = [filter imageByFilteringImage:im];
    NSArray * imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i, nil];

    for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
    {
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andSize:size];

        BOOL append_ok = NO;
        int j = 0;
        while (!append_ok && j < 30)
        {
            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
            {
                printf("appending %d attemp %d\n", frameCount, j);

                CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) kRecordingFPS);
                append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];

                if(buffer)
                    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
            }
            else
            {
                printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (!append_ok) {
            printf("error appending image %d times %d\n", frameCount, j);
        }
        frameCount++;
    }


    //Finish the session:
    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWriting];
    NSLog(@"Write Ended");
}
```

I tried to check if the video is compatible using

```
UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath)
```

and I found out that the video isn't compatible

but i don't know why or how to fix this

Comment: Wow, this code is a bit of a mess right now.... Perhaps a stint over at SE:Code Review would be necessary after an answer is found.

Comment: Check the images resolution, iDevices have pretty limited playback formats support. IMG_1650 looks like a camera photo file while iPad supports only 1080p h264.

Comment: THX @A-Live
I replaced the image with a smaller one and it worked 
isn't there a way to over come this?
or do i have to resize all my images?

Comment: TIL http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ exists. thanks @CodaFi!

Answer (score 1):

The videoPath

```
NSString* exportVideoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",documentsDirectoryPath,@"a.mov"];
```

is wrong. You are missing '/' separator.

Change it to this

```
NSString* exportVideoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath,@"a.mov"];
```

Hope this should sove your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by A-Live in a previous comment

the problem turned out to be the size of the image was too big

is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: One hint - feel free to use the `Edit` button below the question to keep it updated. Please also take into consideration the site is worldwide accessed meaning the timezones might be very different.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by overcome ? I believe you are fine to send the file from documents to any backend server to store it and other devices with a better (you know what i mean) video support will be able to play it. But exceeding the OS limitations will not likely go well even if possible by some 'hack'.

I mean 1080p is the greatest video file resolution to be at library as the media at library **must** be playable. Still you could store the file at the app documents and decode it manually, sounds like an interesting task :) Make sure you are not going to sync it with iCloud though to avoid huge traffic leaks making the customers crazy.